# How to set focus listener on TextInput in react native

Tags: android, react-native

Hi I am using `TextInput` in my react native application. I want to open Date Dialog on clicking on `TextInput`. It came in my mind if it allows to listen focus events then it may work for me.

I didn't find any word around for this. Does anyone know how to set focus listener on `TextInput` in react native ?

```
<TextInput
  style={{
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginTop: 8
  }}
  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
  placeholder={strings.schedule_date}
  onKeyPress={keyPress => console.log(keyPress)}
/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply click event on TextInput in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781513/how-to-apply-click-event-on-textinput-in-react-native)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onFocus` prop for this. It is a Callback that is called when the text input is focused. You can read this [document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onfocus).

Comment: When this component opens then it receivers focus on this also which should not. Do you have any work around to listen click events on `TextInput` ?

Comment: @VahidBoreiri your link is broken

Comment: @anivaler The old link was removes. I edited the link.