# How to apply click event on TextInput in react native

Tags: android, react-native

Hi I am using `TextInput` in my react native application. I want to open Date Dialog on clicking on `TextInput`. I didn't find any work around to apply click event on `TextInput`. Does anyone know how to do this in react native ?

```
<TextInput
  style={{
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginTop: 8
  }}
  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
  placeholder={strings.schedule_date}
  onKeyPress={keyPress => console.log(keyPress)}
/>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `onFocus` prop to know when the user has selected that `TextInput`.

```
<TextInput
  style={{
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginTop: 8
  }}
  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
  placeholder={strings.schedule_date}
  onKeyPress={keyPress => console.log(keyPress)}
  onFocus={() => yourCode()}
/>
```

Unless you have `autofocus={true}`, this will work. You can find more documentation about `onFocus` here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onfocus

Answer (score 25):

**Add** `pointerEvents="none"` on `TextInput`

**Example**

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("Pressed")}>
  <TextInput
   pointerEvents="none"
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: how this will apply click event on textinput?

Comment: Thanks. I was facing same issue on iOS. Android was working fine.    pointerEvents="none" did the trick

Comment: I'm not getting events to register when using `onTouchStart` for Android so this seems to be the correct approach!

Answer (score 11):

One more way to perform TextInput click

```
TextInput onTouchStart

<TextInput
  style={{
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginTop: 8
  }}
  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
  placeholder={strings.schedule_date}
  onTouchStart={()=>  console.log("Pressed...")}
  editable={false}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use **onTouchStart** property to call any function on click event

```
 <TextInput
      style={{
        height: 40,
        borderColor: "gray",
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginTop: 8
      }}
      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
      placeholder={strings.schedule_date}
      onKeyPress={keyPress => console.log(keyPress)}
    onTouchStart={() => "Call your function here"}
    />
```